# how to set same card size in html page

Tags: html, size, height, card

In my website, alll cards have same size except the bottom left one. i have used same size of images for the card. can anyone explain how to fix it

[image]

```html
<div class="row mx_auto">
        {% for product in products.object_list %}
        <div class="my_bottom_margin col-9 col-sm-12 col-md-4  xol-lg-4">
            <div class="card text-center" style="min-width:18rem;">
                <a href="{{product.get_url}}"><img class="card-img-top my_image" src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="{{product.name}}"></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
                    <p>{{product.price}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

css

```css
.my_image {
    width :100%;
    height:auto;
}
.my_bottom_margin{
    margin-bottom :10px;
}
.card-body h4
{
font-size:14px;
text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing:.2em;
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide the CSS ?

Comment: @Dave111 updated. please check the question

Answer (score 1):

Due to the lack of more CSS, image links etc. Im not 100% able to find out what is going on in this case. However, the problem might be in the image parent div, in this case tha `a` tag.

First thing i would try would be to set the `a` tag to the same fixed/max `height` and `width` as the images (if they are all the same as you say), and setting the `img` within the `a` parent to take up 100% of its height and width, so like this.

```
.card a {
   height:100px; /*original image height*/ /*or max-height*/
   width:100px; /*original image width*/ /*or max-width*/
}

.my_image {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```